# How to Evaluate VS Code Environment Variables in Extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I asked a similar question to this a couple weeks ago, but I think because it was so specific and lengthy, I did not get an answer. [See original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61830915/). I'll try and ask a more direct question this time--

I'm currently writing a VS Code extension. Is there a function built into the VS Code API that when given a string as input, allows for evaluation of environment variables, like those used in the `tasks.json` file? Full list of variables can be found here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference.

Such a function would take in a string containing environment variables and information about the workspace, then evaluate the environment variables in it. **Example**: `"${workspaceFolder}_${fileBasenameNoExt}.txt"` → `"myWokspaceFolderName_myFileName.txt`

I know VS Code has the functionality built in (as it is used in tasks) but I don't know how they do it and/or if I am able to use that functionality without having to rebuild it for my extension. **What's the best way to implement this functionality in my extension?**

Comment: I'm looking for the same answer.

Comment: @ATL_DEV I ended up implementing my own variable resolver. See: https://github.com/Antyos/vscode-openscad/blob/43e709478ff68f3b02c878a458cc2264fa2e1630/src/variableResolver.ts

Comment: I added an answer. I hope I understood your question as it seemed identical to mine. I think your code might be better though.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to check a variable's runtime value is to create a VS Code task to output the variable value to the console. For example, to see the resolved value for **${workspaceFolder}**, you can create and run (**Terminal > Run Task**) the following simple 'echo' task in *tasks.json*:

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "echo",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "echo ${workspaceFolder}"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: My question was not about seeing the output of the variables but about being able to use the variable resolver used by `tasks.json` in other parts of a VS Code extension. My use case was I had a config in one of my extensions that defines the file name format when exporting files and I wanted the user to be able to use the same variables as `tasks.json`. At the time of asking the question, VS Code did not (and still may not) reveal that part of its API, so I think I just copied from its source code.

Comment: OK. So you want to resolve them programmatically. I believe VSCode is open source, so you might be able to find the API function responsible for resolving variable.

Comment: That's precisely what I did! (I forgot to add an answer to my own question). Take a look at: https://github.com/Antyos/vscode-openscad/blob/43e709478ff68f3b02c878a458cc2264fa2e1630/src/variableResolver.ts

Comment: Is there a reason you couldn't import the resolver service and use it?

Comment: I can't remember my specific reasoning from 2 years ago, but if I recall correctly, at the time it did not seem that VS Code exposed the variable resolver in their extension API, and I was unable to find a way to import it.